# Conditional operator in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, conditional-operator

I really like this:

```
var value = maxValue > minValue ? minValue : maxValue;
```

Is there something equally concise in Coffescript?

Comment: Thank you very much for not calling it "the ternary operator".

Comment: @MarkWilden why shouldn't he? it's an established term

Comment: If you look for ternary operator for coffescript you find it right away.

Comment: @MarkWilden: You got 5 upvotes, so it seems quite a few people agree with you, but would you please explain why?

Comment: @Zaz `conditional operator` is  easier to be remembered than `ternary operator`

Comment: Because frontend devs aren't expected to have a CS background, so terms like 'ternary' are foreign?

Comment: "The trouble with 'the ternary operator' is that it describes what it *looks like,* not what it *does.*" -- Eric Lippert, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/18/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary.aspx (in the comments)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
value = if maxValue > minValue then minValue else maxValue
```

Comment: You can also do this:

``value = `maxValue > minValue ? minValue : maxValue` ``

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic: You might want to change your comment to an answer :) At same character count but less readable in my opinion, this also works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23915351/750216

Comment: If think the proper solution is: `value = Math.min minValue, maxValue`

Comment: Okay, now how do you write this on multiple lines? Any other way than using the line continuation sign `\`?

Answer (score 20):

There is a *more* concise option in both javascript and coffeescript :)

```
value = Math.min(minValue, maxValue)
```

Comment: in coffee, `value = Math.min minValue, maxValue` ;)

Comment: I don't think the question was referring to the actual content, but to the ability to do it all on one line. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Wrong as it does not addresses the question. The OP asks about `Conditional operator in Coffeescript` and how to write it in, giving the `JS` example. It is just an example and has nothing to do with the actual syntax problem.

Answer (score 12):

As Răzvan Panda points out, my comment may actually one of the better answers:

```
value = `maxValue > minValue ? minValue : maxValue`
```

Comment: What is the function of the quotes in your line of code?

Comment: The backticks cause the line to execute prior to assignment.

Answer (score 10):

This is a case where it feels like CoffeeScript has competing philosophies:

1. Be concise
2. Don't be redundant

Since all operations return a result, the if/then/else way of doing things gives you what you need.  Adding the ?/: operator is redundant.

This is where I wish they'd give us the ?/: ternary operator even though it is redundant... it simply reads better than the if/then/else variant.

Just my 2c.

Comment: There's no way to have the `a ? b : c` ternary in CoffeeScript without ambiguity, since `a ? b` has a meaning ("`a` if it's non-null, `b` otherwise), and `b: c` has one as well (`{b: c}`).

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this:

```
value = if maxValue > minValue then minValue else maxValue
```

It will compile like your code.

Answer (score 3):

## Below is the fact:

In the documentation, there's a section titled **"Conditionals, Ternaries, and Conditional Assignment"**. This leads one to believe that coffeescript supports

```
condition ? when-true : when-false
```

but in fact it does not.

### Below is the information about the patch which will solve this issue

Here's the patch (and it's pushed to **[coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/)**):

http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/commit/ec2d358ae3c82e9888c60695d7cce05edde0c55a

## Examples:

```
mood = greatlyImproved if singing

if happy and knowsIt
  clapsHands()
  chaChaCha()
else
  showIt()

date = if friday then sue else jill

options or= defaults
```

Comment: `if then else` **is** a ternary operation, it just has different syntax.

Comment: in coffee script, if else statement is written in one line statement.

Comment: what i meant is that a ternary operation is defined as *an operation with three elements*. A one-liner `if then else` statement classifies as *ternary*. The correct term for the "ternary" operator in javascript is **conditional operator** anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
value = maxValue > minValue && minValue || maxValue
```

This is actually not correct, check the comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: This is a valid answer actually, only a little less readable.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda No, it is not a valid answer, because it is doing slightly different thing than requested and the difference is not described/documented in the answer. Eg. if `minValue` equals `0` and `maxValue` equals `5`, then `maxValue > minValue ? minValue : maxValue` would return `0`, while `maxValue > minValue && minValue || maxValue` would return `5`.

Comment: @pepkin88: That is correct, this answer does not work when being passed a falsy value for minValue and the condition is true.