# JavaScript with coffescript syntax- if condition : optimize if statement structure

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, coffeescript

I have a function and I'm testing 4 variables, I want to optimize the structure of my if statement test, can some one help ? :

```
$scope.filterActivated = ->
    if $scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.from || $scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.to || $scope.postParams.options.template_id || $scope.displayOptions.query.length > 0
      return true
    else
      return false
```

Comment: what exactly you want to optimize? Looks not bad at all.

Comment: `return ($scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.from || $scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.to || $scope.postParams.options.template_id || $scope.displayOptions.query.length > 0)`

Comment: hi @Timggwp and thanks for your comment , it look good this structure ? is there any other syntax that look much better than that ?

Comment: are you looking for destructing ??

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this isn't valid syntax for JS `$scope.filterActivated = ->`. If this is an arrow function there has to be `= () =>` for no parameters

Comment: @MaxBaldwin it seems CoffeeScript

Comment: Also forgot to mention that you are comparing only the last field. It will always return true if `$scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.from` is not undefined

Comment: @MaxBaldwin it's CoffeeScript syntax

Comment: thanks guys for your answers :)

Comment: If you are using coffeeScript consider using the existential operator.  for example: `$scope.displayOptions.query.length` will blow up if scope.displayOptions.query is undefined.  you could use the existential operator to guard against it blowing up by doing `scope.displayOptions.query?length` to keep from blowing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove `true/false` and optimize it a little bit like this:

```
$scope.filterActivated = ->
  options = $scope.postParams.options
  options.scopes.report.from or options.scopes.report.to or options.template_id or $scope.displayOptions.query.length > 0
```

Edit: JS for you:

```
$scope.filterActivated = () => {
  let options = $scope.postParams.options;
  return options.scopes.report.from || options.scopes.report.to || options.template_id || $scope.displayOptions.query.length > 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by optimizing, but a shorthand of that could be:

```
$scope.filterActivated = ->
    $scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.from
    || $scope.postParams.options.scopes.report.to
    || $scope.postParams.options.template_id
    || $scope.displayOptions.query.length;
```

Edit:

Initially, I used the ternary syntax, but that's not supported by CoffeeScript. For reference [Ternary operation in CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146123/1869996)

Edit 2:

Reduced it a bit more, @user633183 suggested using `Boolean` but I think this gives the same result.

Comment: remove `? true : false` and it does the same thing – better `-> Boolean (a || b || c || d)`

Comment: `... then true else false` is the same anti-pattern. just remove it.

Comment: If you want to force it to return a boolean, you can wrap the whole expression in `!!(...)`.

Comment: @user633183 can you point a reference where it says is an anti-pattern, I'm curious.

Comment: @thinkxl `if (condition) then return true else false` is the same thing as `return Boolean (condition)` – or `return !!(condition)` as Barmar suggests

Comment: @user633183 that's true, but I see it as different syntax, I was asking about a reference where it says `then/else` is an anti-pattern.