# Can I add an else to a simplified if statement?

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript

I'll be honest, I could not think of what to address this problem as.

I was looking on Coffeescript.org to see if there was a nicer way to handle multiple OR's in an if statement

They showed an example of displaying this:

```
if (pick === 47 || pick === 92 || pick === 13) {
    winner = true;
}
```

List this this:

```
winner = yes if pick in [47, 92, 13]
```

My problem is that I can seem to put an **else** at the end of the **if** statement when I have it formatted the new way. Are you even allowed to?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170510/1596731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `if...then` if you want to use an else:

```
winner = if pick in [47, 92, 13] then yes else no
```

However, you can still do multi-line `if`s:

```
if pick in [47, 92, 13]
  winner = true
else
  winner = false
```

Also, note that the `in` operator returns a boolean, so you can assign that directly.

```
winner = pick in [47, 92, 13]
```

is equivalent to my first example.

Comment: Sorry, meant the 3rd option.